# Multipart/mixed e-mail not displayed correctly in Outlook/Microsoft Mail, text displays as attachment

Tags: email, outlook, multipart

I'm trying to create e-mail with `multipart/mixed` content, with 2 HTML BodyParts (no attachments).

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 9 Dec 2021 13:44:01 +0100
Message-ID: <id@localhost>
Subject: This is Subject
From: test <foo@bar.com>
To: foo2@bar.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----main_boundary"

------main_boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----header_boundary"

------header_boundary
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Header before the main body</h2>
------header_boundary--

------main_boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundary1
Content-Disposition: inline

--boundary1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<b>Just HTML</b>

--boundary1--


------main_boundary--
```

This e-mail renders fine in all clients even mobile ones I've tested except Outlook and Windows Mail. Seems like Microsoft's clients ignore the Second body part and displays only the `Header before the main body` part.

Is there any workaround? I don't want to create just one html content.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a work around, I have searched and not found one. There is an article here suggesting that inline parts don't all get displayed in Outlook: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/mixed-ing-it-up-multipart-mixed-messages-and-you/ba-p/585841